# Populate MySQL table from Text file

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, text

This should be an easy one.  I need to populate a table from a text file.  Basically, I'd like to do this in a linux shell script. Thanks!!

Example:

- **MySQL Table**

Item color shape size

- **Textfile**

car blue round small

carrot red square big

apple green round medium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run a query like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE yourTable
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And then all you need is to write a tiny shell script, executing the query.

## Edit:

A complete script could look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql databaseName<<EOFMYSQL
 LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE yourTable
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
EOFMYSQL
```

The script could be executed like this:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

You probably run into user issues, since the shell does not handle mysql directly. Try looking into how you can execute mysql without logging in. This should be part of just about any mysql backup script :-)

Comment: Thanks Ragnar123!   How would the complete script look?

Comment: Is it possible to do this "on the fly" with a .txt.gz input avoiding write the uncompressed .txt on disk?

Comment: I ended up creating a ramdisk in my script and `pigz -dc > $ramdisk` the files I needed to import.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at [the LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) documentation, that should let you import data from that format without even writing a script.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax. Echoing a simle query to the mysql client binary should do it.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE is the way used to do that. Consider csv format.